# Batch file FOR command

Tags: variables, for-loop, batch-file

I need to know some basic information on the for command in batch scripts. One thing I want to know is why its %%variable instead of %variable%.

Comment: Can you give an example of where you have seen this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%A` is for use on command lines only.

`%%A` is used when used in batch files.

Comment: YEh but whats the relationship between %%A and %A%

Comment: %A% is a variable, but %%A is the looping variable

Comment: In Loop structure, e.g: FOR, there is a looping variable, you can read more here `http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php`. Hope this help :D

Answer (score 0):

From [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html):

> If you are using the FOR command at the command line rather than in a batch program, specify %parameter instead of %%parameter

So %%param is for batch scripts and %param is for live commands. Greg is right, %param% is a different kind of variable. The "variable" in the FOR command exists only that scope, while environment %variables% persist in a wider scope.

Answer (score 0):

The single-percent `%a` syntax indicates a local variable within a batch file.

The percent-bracketed `%foo%` represents the value of an environment variable named `foo`.

Comment: Okay thanks I think it will be easier If I just ask you simple questions instead of a summary. In what would u accomplish by using the for command.

Comment: The `for` statement is used for many things. Try `for /?` at a command prompt to get the documentation.